# Receiving large amount of data using StreamSockets

Tags: c#, .net, network-programming, uwp

I have problem of receiving large amount of data from StreamSocket in our W10 client. During testing of one of our packets in our protocol there was problem with deserializing data. It was found that data was cut and had 260B although in the definition of packet says it should contain more data. Testing the same packet on our Windows Phone 8 client with the same input gave more data (around 26kB) than w10 client. It was checked on the server that the same amount of data is sent to both clients.

First attempt of solving was to increase `DataReader.LoadAsync()` buffer up to 10 MB but still the same small amount of data was received. Then I checked the connection using WireShark and turn out that all data is received by windows but only part of it is consumed by client. Next attempt to solve the problem was to use DataReader.LoadAsync in loop but it is stopping on the much smaller packets. It was found in this moment that the rest of data for the packet could be read afterwards. Then `Task.Delay(1000)` was used. It worked and all data was received but that it is not a good solution. I searched the StackOverflow, Microsoft forums and google, but there are no solution. StackOverflow's suggestions for the question are not answering the problem.

After a while I tried to read from `StreamSocket.InputStream` buffer in loop by fixed amount of bytes and using `StreamSocket.InputStream.ReadAsync` with all possible combination of parameters. It worked with parameter `InputStreamOptions.Partial` and `InputStreamOptions.None` but it stopped at the ReadAsync when reached the end of packet. I also used `StreamSocketListener` with `StreamSocket` but it didn't work either.

The question is what are methods of receiving large amount of data using StreamSockets and DataReader?

Comment: Servers often limit data at around 10MB.  So you may just be dealing with an operating system limit that can be changed.  Often to work around limits I have had to split files to send and then recombine.  I have dealt with issues like this for 40 years.  Unix has a nice command split() which was made just for these type issues.

Comment: It is not the case of too large data. From server in the program I received around 250 bytes. After I paused a Task for a second before receiving data it got around 26 kB.

Comment: Async data may not come all at one time.  You must specify where the data actually ends.  Normally one (or more) of following techniques are used 1) Ascii : Terminate each message with know character not part of message 2) Ascii or Binary : Add byte count to beginning of message 3) Ascii or Binary : Fixed length messages.  A stream has not end and it is up to application to determine an algorithm that specifies end of each message/data.